# JSF 2 error "Unable to instantiate ExpressionFactory" on App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, netbeans, jsf-2

With a new JSF 2.0 app created in NetBeans 6.9.1 this error message appears in the log file on startup on the production server:

> com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
>   contextInitialized: Initializing
>   Mojarra 2.0.2 (FCS b10) for context ''
>
> com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory
>   createInstance: JSF1048:
>   PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations
>   present.  ManagedBeans methods marked
>   with these annotations will have said
>   annotations processed.
>
> **> com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
>   installExpressionFactory: Unable to
>   instantiate ExpressionFactory
>   'com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl'**
>
> Failed startup of context
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.RuntimeAppEngineWebAppContext@7616ad{/,/base/data/home/apps/scroogedemo/1.350894485313261302}
>   com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException:
>   It appears the JSP version of the
>   container is older than 2.1 and unable
>   to locate the EL RI expression
>   factory,
>   com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.  If
>   not using JSP or the EL RI, make sure
>   the context initialization parameter,
>   com.sun.faces.expressionFactory, is
>   properly set.     at
>   com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.registerELResolverAndListenerWithJsp(ConfigureListener.java:638)

The app uses the JSF 2.0 reference implementation provided by NetBeans, which seems to include the EL RI (package javax.faces.el).

The application runs fine in the development server. I use these configuration entries in web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    ...
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Production</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.enableThreading</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

I checked the page https://sites.google.com/a/wildstartech.com/adventures-in-java/Java-Platform-Enterprise-Edition/JavaServer-Faces/sun-javaserver-faces-reference-implementation/configuring-jsf-20-to-run-on-the-google-appengine/javaserverfaces-20-and-google-app-engine-compatibility-issues for information on this error but this problem is not covered there.

**Update**: the page mentioned above said that the el-api and el-impl files need to be included in the project. They are not in the NetBeans libraries list, so they have not been uploaded in the server deployment procedure. I guess they are provided by the local development server - but missing on the production GAE. It turned out to be the solution, see below.

Comment: Was your web.xml declared conform Servlet 2.5? The exception suggests that it was incorrectly set to 2.4 or that the servletcontainer itself is *actually* a Servlet 2.4 container.

Comment: @BalusC see my update, it is version 2.5 and this seems to be the GAE level (as per http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml.html#About_Deployment_Descriptors)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deploying the app with el-api-2.2.jar and el-impl-2.2.jar solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

just add this:

```
    public ServletContextInitializer servletContextInitializer() {
          .....

            sc.setInitParameter("com.sun.faces.expressionFactory", "org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl");
          .....
}
```

Comment: Is this really needed in google-app-engine?  And since what version?

Comment: No, don't really . I working with  Spring Boot
Primefaces 7.0,  JSF2 Mojarra 2.3.9, JSE 13, Spring Boot 2.2.5

Comment: UI Frontend lib plays no role i think. First of all it should be initialize the EL feature: you can make it so as describe above - in 
Spring Boot project w/o web.xml,  or init this feature in web.xm, l if you have it in your project. This is a part of Server initialisation, and not of UI.

Comment: Ahhhhh, now we're getting down to it.... Yes, spring boot requires configs like this. This question is NOT about spring boot, but for google app engine. So this answer is in no way related to the question in my opinion.

Comment: as i say -  where is no significant difference: this is servlet's container feature an not of UI Framework one. If u using web.xml just insert     <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
    </context-param>